# Template from Atmosphere JS in Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-packages

I'm just getting started with Meteor JS and have looked into some packages on Atmospherejs.com. I've come across packages like accounts-ui/accounts-facebook/etc. I have found related files of these packages in my projectRoot/.meteor/local/build/programs/server and projectRoot/.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser.

I do this in my main html file, and I believe this is a template.

{{> loginButtons}}

Now, I also believe that a template is a piece of HTML. I've gone through various folders/directories created in my project directory and didn't find any template related to this 'loginButtons'. Where exactly is the template for loginButtons is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

loginButtons template is defined in accounts-ui package

Answer (score 0):

The package provides you with some helper functions. Actually, as you can see from the way you call it in the template {{> loginButtons}}. The package makes for you some ready functionalities for your templates. The best way to configure each package layout or functions is to have a look on the documentation provided in github or on the package page on atmosphere.js. You can configure the accounts packages layout and functions according to your preferences by using `Accounts.ui.config`. For example you could add extra fields to the form:

```
Accounts.ui.config({
    passwordSignupFields: "USERNAME_AND_EMAIL"
  });
```

If you want to configure the layout of other packages have a look on the css classes of the source provided on github and configure them in your css. So you do not need to find the files in your application.